# Terraform local env. variables vs cloud variables

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud, terraform-cli

I'm learning currently terraform and I found a situation which is not clear to me.

I've configured my TF project to use TF cloud to store state file. Obviously this is a good practice as I don't want to store the file locally. I have couple of variables which I would like to declare as env. variables; i.e. TF_VAR_region="xyz".

The problem is that when I want to use this variable `tf plan` is saying that variable is unknown (even if it is set locally). When I set the variable in the TF cloud workspace or as variable set assigned to the workspace. it works but it shows me:

```
│ Warning: Value for undeclared variable
│ 
│ The root module does not declare a variable named "region" but a value was
│ found in file
│ "/home/tfc-agent/.tfc-agent/component/terraform/runs/run-XXXX/terraform.tfvars".
│ If you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the
│ configuration.
│ 
│ To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide
│ certain "global" settings to all configurations in your organization. To
│ reduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the -compact-warnings option.
```

I don't want to set variables in variables.tf file because one of those variables is sensitive and I don't want to commit it into the repository. Also I kind of don't want to declare manually variables in TF cloud since, ... well it's manual activity where I can just forget that I have set something somewhere. It would be better for me to have everything in "one place" so to speak (i.e. in readme I would have description that I have to set env variables for the process to work).

Is there a way how can I use TF cloud to store state file but at the same time be able to use local variables? i.e. when running localy terraform apply.

Comment: If you just define a variable without assigning a value, that will not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set variable **values** inside `variables.tf` file

```
variable "var_name" {
  description = "Secret variable"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}
```

`terraform` will prompt you to set variable value if it didn't set else where:

```bash
$ terraform plan

var.var_name
  Secret variable

  Enter a value:
```

In other way defining of variable inside configuration is a good style and clearly describing terraform what variables should be set before `plan` or `apply`

> well it's manual activity where I can just forget that I have set something somewhere

And that is one more reason to define variable inside configuration. `terraform` will raise error if you forget to set `something` that is describing in configuration `somewhere`. Because error is easier to debug than silence

Here is an [article](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/sensitive-variables) about variables that may be helpful

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didn't think about creating two different tfvars files. That would be actually quite a good solution. One with generic variables (not sensitive) and one with sensitive ones which will be excluded from commits.